# Query errors during Availability Group failover

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, high-availability, alwayson

I have a C# OLTP application that runs against SQL Server 2012. I want it to run without interruption in the case of a failover when its database is in an AlwaysOn Availability Group. In order to recover from transactions that are interrupted due to a failover, I have wrapped the C# SqlCommand object with another class (RetryableSqlCommand) that catches exceptions related to failovers (connection dropped, could not harden remote transaction, etc.) and automatically retries them after an exponential backoff delay. In small test apps, this code works exactly as I would like. When run under moderate load (couple hundred transactions per second) in the full OLTP app, I get errors when I manually failover the database.

The error always occurs in one of the most frequently called stored procedures that inserts one master record and 4 detail records. The stored procedure always returns the IDs of the inserted master and detail records as OUTPUT parameters. The C# code looks something like this:

```
using (RetryableSqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandText = "InsertComplexItem";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  // add sproc input parameters for master and detail records
  await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

  // retrieve IDs of inserted records
  var masterId = (long)(cmd.Parameters["MasterId"].Value);   <-- InvalidCastException
  var detail1Id = (long)(cmd.Parameters["Detail1Id"].Value);
  var detail2Id = (long)(cmd.Parameters["Detail2Id"].Value);
  var detail3Id = (long)(cmd.Parameters["Detail3Id"].Value);
  var detail4Id = (long)(cmd.Parameters["Detail4Id"].Value);
}
```

I get an InvalidCastException at the line noted above because, as I determined from debug logging, the IDs are coming back from the stored procedure as DBNulls. So far as I can tell, that should never happen because the stored procedure inserts all the records in a single transaction. If the transaction were interrupted, there should be an exception that would be caught and retried by the RetryableSqlCommand class. Any explanations for the InvalidCastException?

Comment: did you tried `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`

Comment: @ShwetaPathak Just for kicks, I tried the synchronous `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and the same error occurs.